# How to remove 'select all' option from multiselect listbox

Tags: jquery

I have a multiselect dropdown. There is a 'Select All' which I want to remove as requested by my client. How can I do that?

```
<asp:ListBox ID="CmbInterviewer" runat="server" SelectionMode="multiple" CssClass="form-border"></asp:ListBox>
```

```js
$("#CmbInterviewer").multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  numberDisplayed: 10,
  nonSelectedText: '<-Select->',
  buttonWidth: '100%',
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  maxHeight: 200
});
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder what the `includeSelectAllOption` option does...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try passing

```
includeSelectAllOption: false
```

into multi-select settings.